# Where can I find example answers to the Chinese HSK6 test composition 书写 (aka 缩写 or "question 101")?

Tags: chinese, hsk

The Chinese HSK6 test has a section called 书写 where you're given an ~1000 character passage and 10 minutes to read it.  Here's the introduction:

> 第101题：缩写。（1）仔细阅读下面这篇文章，时间为10分钟，阅读时不能抄写、记录。（2）10分钟后，监考收回阅读材料，请你将这篇文章缩写成一篇短文，时间为35分钟。（3）标题自拟。只需复述文章内容，不需加入自己的观点。（4）字数为400左右。（5）请把作文直接写在答题卡上。

Afterwards, your task is to <s>summarize</s> create an abridged version of it in ~400 characters.  An example *question* from a past exam is [here](http://hummedia.manchester.ac.uk/schools/salc/centres/confucius/hsk/pastpapers/hsk6/H61332-reading-writing-paper.pdf).

**Question**: Where can I find example *answers* to the Chinese HSK6 test composition?

It's hard for me to tell what I'm supposed to write.  Judging from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/3o1rkl/hsk6_writing_section_questions_possibly/), it's more about reproducing the original material from memory.

Thus far, I've found:

- Two student answers are critiqued in the Coursera HSK6 lessons [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6/lecture/g5u7g/zhi-shi-yu-ji-neng-di-20ke) (answer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYjm.jpg)) and [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6/lecture/FRLxH/zhi-shi-yu-ji-neng-di-40ke) (answer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4q7S.jpg)).
- <s>I *think* the book 21天征服新HSK六级写作 contains example answers (but I'm not sure).</s> I bought the book; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought the book 21天征服新HSK六级写作 (the 2015 version), and it contains 8 examples (although each of them seems to exceed the 400 character limit).

1. 女儿的秘密 [pp. 64-65]
2. 无声的婚礼 [pp. 74-75]
3. 国王的爱好 [pp. 84-85]
4. 两张借条 [pp. 102-103]
5. 辞职 [pp. 112-113]
6. 天使的翅膀 [pp. 125-126]
7. 兔子的故事 [pp. 137-138]
8. 两颗钉子 [pp. 150-151]

There's also these which seem similar:

1. 北京的符号 [pp.46-47]
2. 游北海 [pp 94-96]
3. 幸福是最后一锹土 [pp. 163-164]

It also explains other aspects, such as how punctuation, spacing, etc., should be used on the particular HSK6 answer sheet.

---

The textbook 汉语水平考试 模拟试题集（第2版） gives answers to its 10 mock exams, including the 缩写 section. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TZSw.jpg) is a photo of one example.

---

According to [Emory University's examples](http://confucius.emory.edu/hsk_and_resources/hsk/hsk_samples.html), this is the standard HSK6 answer card, which in fact has 25 * 20 = 500 boxes for the composition question:

[image: HSK6 examination card]